# Unable to configure survey in post-chat settings

Tags: liveagent, survey

I'm a new developer to the salesforce environment. I'm working on Live web chat configuration in service cloud and was asked to provide survey link at the end of chat.
I'm trying to use a survey link on the "post-chat settings" on Embedded services->Chat Settings->Edit chat settings page. The option seems dis-abled.[image]

I have enabled surveys in my org and have a few default surveys which I'm able to access manually.
Can someone suggest if I'm missing any configuration change or doing anything wrong..

Any help is highly appreciated.. :)

Comment: As per the documentation https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=snapins_chat_configure_post_chat_survey.htm&type=5  ,this feature is available with the Salesforce Feedback Management license. Can you ensure the license is available?

Comment: For more information on licensing see https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=concept_add_on_license.htm&type=5

Comment: @Swetha The links says to use the advanced features like merge fields in surveys we might need that license. Also, the help text beside 'survey' field(in the above screenshot) says I need to enable surveys in my org(which I did) and I need to allowlist my domain if I'm using my chat on the same domain. But allowlisting is disabled for me and says 'You don't have enough permission to use this feature'. fyi, I'm using the System Administrator profile.

Comment: Where are you trying to allowlist the domain?Can you confirm it is on Setup>Session settings> Trusted Domains for Visualforce and Survey Inline Frames

Comment: Also, I rechecked the documentation https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=concept_add_on_license.htm&type=5. "Use Merge fields" is one of the capabilities of the Salesforce Feedback Management license. Doc also states "Gather post-chat feedback" (which is your requirement)as a capability that needs Salesforce Feedback Management license.

Comment: Thanks Swetha. Apologies for the confusion. Looks like you are right. The license and permission are the blockers. Also, I was able to allowlist the domain in Setup>Session settings> Trusted Domains for Visualforce and Survey Inline Frames. Looks like I need to buy the license to continue. By the way, is there any other work around to get this done with out the license. I know by manually posting the survey link at the end of chat  using quick text before closing the window is one way.

Comment: You can try Post-chat Survey Integration. Steps mentioned in documentation https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000333183&type=1&mode=1 on how to paste the link to the survey into the Post-Chat URL field.Let me know if this helps

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to check the permission set section given in second section of this module.

https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/projects/design-and-distribute-surveys-with-salesforce-feedback-management/get-started-with-salesforce-feedback-management

Hope This helps.